# MYSQL - calculate values based on other ID

Tags: mysql

```
ItemID Quantity CustID
1      1        1000 
6      1        1000 
7      2        1000 
2      12       1001 
3      24       1001 
4      16       1001 
2      1        1002
```

how should I calculate the quantity based on each custID purchased?
i.e.

```
CustID Quantity
1000   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a particular customer ID you can use

```
select custid, sum(quantity)
from table_name
where custid=1000
```

Or for all customer id's you can use

```
select custid, sum(quantity)
from table_name
group by custid
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/664c2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple `SUM`:

```
SELECT CustID,SUM(Quantity) as Quantity
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CustID
```

You need to learn more about aggregate functions. Read more [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: Mate don't you think a `group by` is required here..

Comment: SELECT custID, SUM(Quantity) as Quantity FROM Purchase GROUP BY CustID; but your answer was helpful. Thanks!